# Best compression settings in Inno Setup compiler

Tags: inno-setup

What are the best settings for the smallest file size output?

[image]

That can equal or surpass this setting in FreArc

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the best compression use:

```
[Setup]
SolidCompression=yes
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
LZMAUseSeparateProcess=yes
LZMADictionarySize=1048576
LZMANumFastBytes=273
```

- Use defaults for other compression-related directives.
- Run the compiler on x64 system.
- With the `SolidCompression`, it helps, if you order files in the `[Files]` section by an extension and similarity. Though the [solid compression is not recommended for huge installs](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_solidcompression).
- You can use [`LZMANumBlockThreads`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_lzmanumblockthreads) to [speed up the compression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53987812/850848).

With this settings, you will need up to 11 GB of memory on the machine that runs the compiler; and up to 1 GB of memory on the system that runs the installer.

For details, refer to the [`Compression` directive documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_compression).

---

Though I'm not sure, if you can match FreeArc even with this settings.

If you want to [use FreeArc compression, use `unarc.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42925684/850848).

---

Note that ISTools does not allow the `lzma2`, as that was introduced in the [Inno Setup 5.3.9](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.3.9). Always use the latest version of Inno Setup.